# Mutate to create new column that indicates if a horse has won at today's track so far this season

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some horse racing data which for a season is grouped by race and each row is a particular horse in that race and where it finished and how much weight it was carrying and what distance the race was and what track it was run at etc I now use dplyr to group all races by horse so I can investigate various stats that that horse had going into each race that season for example how many races had it won. I am having trouble mutating a new column that is 1 if the horse has won at today's track before this season and 0 if not.

I can get it working for a fixed number of previous races eg 5:

```
Horses <- Horses %>% 
  group_by(horse_name) %>% 
  arrange(desc(date)) %>% 
  mutate(winattrackinlast5runs = ifelse((lead(course,1) == course & lead(pos,1) <= 1) | 
                                          (lead(course,2) == course & lead(pos,2) <= 1) | 
                                          (lead(course,3) == course & lead(pos,3) <= 1) | 
                                          (lead(course,4) == course & lead(pos,4) <= 1) | 
                                          (lead(course,5) == course & lead(pos,5) <= 1), 1, 0)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Buy cannot get it to lead() for each row on all previous rows.

Any ideas much appreciated. Thanks

**Edit.**

Sample data and added explanation.

```
     horse_name       date     course pos
1 Crystal Ocean 2018-10-20      Ascot   2
2 Crystal Ocean 2018-07-28      Ascot   2
3 Crystal Ocean 2018-06-23      Ascot   1
4 Crystal Ocean 2018-09-08 Kempton-AW   2
5 Crystal Ocean 2018-05-19    Newbury   1
6 Crystal Ocean 2018-04-27    Sandown   1
```

Here are the races during 2018 for Crystal Ocean so going into each race I wanted to check if the horse had won at that course already this season and create a new variable to indicate yes/no (1/0)

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? The data seems to have several variables that are not needed for the problem, please edit **the question** with the output of `Horses %>%select(horse_name,date,course,pos) %>%head(20) %>%dput()`.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas please see below, my first time on here so please excuse the formatting;)

Comment: Don't use answers to do that. Like I said, edit the question. (Don't worry, I have already edited the question with the full text of your "answer"). Could you please delete the answer? It is likely to get downvotes.

Comment: Noted thanks @RuiBarradas I would also have applied  %>% arrange(desc(date)) to make the above snippet sorted by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `arrange` the data by `horse_name` and `date`, `group_by` `horse_name` and `course` and for each group we check if any time in the previous `date` the horse has achieved `pos == 1`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  arrange(horse_name, date) %>%
  group_by(horse_name, course) %>%
   mutate(has_won = if (any(pos == 1)) 
                       as.integer(row_number() > which.max(pos == 1)) else 0)
```

On the limited data shared the output looks like

```
#  horse_name   date       course       pos has_won
#  <fct>        <date>     <fct>       <int>   <dbl>
#1 CrystalOcean 2018-04-27 Sandown        1       0
#2 CrystalOcean 2018-05-19 Newbury        1       0
#3 CrystalOcean 2018-06-23 Ascot          1       0
#4 CrystalOcean 2018-07-28 Ascot          2       1
#5 CrystalOcean 2018-09-08 Kempton-AW     2       0
#6 CrystalOcean 2018-10-20 Ascot          2       1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(horse_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "CrystalOcean", class = "factor"), date = structure(c(6L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2018-04-27", "2018-05-19", "2018-06-23", 
"2018-07-28", "2018-09-08", "2018-10-20"), class = "factor"), 
course = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Ascot", 
"Kempton-AW", "Newbury", "Sandown"), class = "factor"), pos = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Great thanks @RonakShah that works very well, saved me a lot of time for all the other features I need to produce.